# Error using typedef and structures

Tags: c, scope, typedef, incomplete-type

```
typedef struct p *q;
int main()
{
    struct p
    {
        int x;
         char y;
         q ptr;
    };
    struct p p = {1, 2, &p};
    printf("%d\n", p.ptr->x);
    return 0;
}
```

The above program throws the following compilation error:

```
1.c:24: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

However, If I move the `typedef` inside main `func` OR if i move  structure definition outside main, there is no compilation error.
Can anyone explain why is it happening??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inner `struct p` is not visible to the program outside the `main` function. Put your structure outside the `main`.
You are confused with the identical name of inner and outer struct `p`. You define the outer `p` as

```
typedef struct p *q;
```

What does it mean? It means that you are defining a new type `q` which is a pointer to the struct `p`. But the problem is that there is no definition of `struct p` type is known here.
It is true that **outer `p` is visible to `main` but inner `p` is not visible to outer `p`**.

Comment: I dont get it? There are not other functions except main.Typedef is global...why is struct p is invisible?

Comment: @hitman47: The outer `struct p` (where `q` is a pointer to) is not the inner struct, although they have the same name.

Comment: Well I didnt understand what u just said

Comment: Whatever is declared outside main (global) should be visible inside main.....so i dont understand, why typdef and struct definition should be together.

Answer (score 2):

`struct p` is defined inside `main()` and it is not visible to outside functions. you can solve compilation error by putting `struct p` outside of the main(global).

Comment: There are no functions outside main and typdef is global....why do i need to place the definition outside?

Answer (score 1):

This is governed by C 2011 6.7.2.3 paragraphs 4 and 5:

> 4 All declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types that have the same scope and use the same tag declare the same type…
>
> 5 Two declarations of structure, union, or enumerated types which are in different scopes or use different tags declare distinct types.

Because `typedef struct p *q;` is outside of any function, it has file scope. Because `struct p { int x; … }` is inside `main`, it has scope inside main. Because these two declarations are in different scopes, they declare distinct types. Thus, the second declaration is not completing the first declaration of `struct p`; it is declaring a different `struct p`.

In turn, that means the type `q` is a pointer to the file-scope `struct p` and is not a pointer to the main-scope `struct p`. Because the file-scope `struct p` is incomplete, attempting to use it results in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this illustrates things a little better:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    int a, b;
};

int main(void) {
    printf( "sizeof outer struct: %zu\n", sizeof(struct foo) );
    struct foo { int a; };
    printf( "sizeof inner struct: %zu\n", sizeof(struct foo) );
    return 0;
}
```

with the output (on my machine, but the exact values don't matter):

```
sizeof outer struct: 8
sizeof inner struct: 4
```

You're hiding the outer definition, similar to how you can hide variables.

HTH